# Casting DirectX interfaces

Tags: c++, com, directx

I'm trying to put interface pointers to different types of shaders in a vector like this:

```
std::vector<ID3D11DeviceChild*> shaders;
ID3D11VertexShader* VS;
// ... instantiate and init VS
shaders.push_back(static_cast<ID3D11DeviceChild*>(VS));
// and when VS is needed again:
ID3D11VertexShader* VS = static_cast<ID3D11VertexShader*>(shaders[i]);
// use VS here
```

My question is whether this method for type casting COM interfaces is safe. I know it would work for normal polymorphic class hierarchies, but I'm not sure about COM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I'd suggest storing **smart pointers** instead of *raw owning pointers* inside an STL container like `std::vector`, e.g.

```
std::vector<CComPtr<ID3D11DeviceChild>> shaders;
```

Using raw *owning* pointers inside STL containers is a source of leaks, potential bugs and exception unsafe code (*observing* raw pointers are fine, though).

To downcast from `ID3D11DeviceChild*` to `ID3D11VertexShader*`, consider using `QueryInterface()` (again, using ATL smart pointers like `CComPtr` simplifies the code):

```
CComPtr<ID3D11VertexShader> spVertexShader;
HRESULT hr = (shaders[i])->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&spVertexShader));
if (FAILED(hr))
    ...
```

---

**PS**

Unless I'm missing something, since `ID3D11VertexShader` is a derived class of `ID3D11DeviceChild`, you don't need the `static_cast` here:

> ```
> shaders.push_back(static_cast<ID3D11DeviceChild*>(VS));
> ```

This should be fine:

```
shaders.push_back(VS);
```

---

**Note on `CAdapt`**

Note that you may need to use `CAdapt` with `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<CAdapt<CComPtr<ID3D11DeviceChild>>> shaders;
```

A conformant C++11 STL implementation should *not* require `CAdapt`, but I think it's necessary at least with VS2008 and VS2010.
I'm not sure about more modern versions of Visual Studio, but it seems they fixed that, e.g.:
you may want to read the paragraph titled *"Resistance to overloaded address-of operators"* in [this Visual C++ blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/09/12/10209291.aspx).

Comment: Thank you Mr. C64. I think I need to read more into COM interfaces to find out why c++ casting wouldn't work well.

Answer (score 1):

`ID3D11VertexShader` inherits from `ID3D11DeviceChild` so you don't even need to use `static_cast<ID3D11DeviceChild*>` to push them to vector. The safer way to downcast vector elements to shader is to use `QueryInterface`:

```
CComPtr<ID3D11VertexShader> vs;
if (S_OK == shaders[i]->QueryInterface(IID_ID3D11VertexShader, 
       reinterpret_cast<void**>(&vs)))
{
   // Use vs here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is safe for as long as you're **absolutely sure** the vector only contains `ID3D11VertexShader`, in which case you should just use it instead of `ID3D11DeviceChild`.

If you intend the vector to contain a mix of interface pointers, each with the common ancestor `ID3D11DeviceChild`, you're better off relying on `QueryInterface`, both for storing into and retrieving from the vector.

Remember, correct code is better than fast code, at least to begin with.

When you profile, **if**, and only if, you find out that `QI` is a bottleneck, then you should do something about it, but I recommend you use a vector of structs which has a pointer to a `ID3D11DeviceChild` and an interface identifier (IID) so you can inspect at runtime which kind of interface pointer you stored:

```
struct DeviceChildPtr {
    ID3D11DeviceChild *ptr;
    REFIID riid;
};

std::vector<DeviceChildPtr> shaders;
// ... instantiate, initialize ...
DeviceChildPtr shader;
shader.ptr = static_cast<ID3D11DeviceChild*>(VS);
shader.iid = IID_ID3D11VertexShader;
shaders.push_back(static_cast<ID3D11DeviceChild*>(shader));

// ...

DeviceChildPtr shader = shaders[i];
// If you only ever use global IIDs, you may replace IsEqualIID with ==
// This is like a half-baked QueryInterface that only checks for a specific IID
if (IsEqualIID(shader.riid, IID_ID3D11VertexShader) {
    ID3D11VertexShader* VS = static_cast<ID3D11VertexShader*>(shader.ptr);
    // ... use ...
}
```

If you ever go through this path, remember to comment why (performance?) and how (casting, safety through runtime interface type check) you're doing it this way instead of using `QueryInterface`.

My guess is, since internally DX itself will most likely use `QueryInterface`, you shouldn't find a bottleneck here.

Comment: Thank you Paulo. I'm indeed intending to use different types of shaders in the same vector array. So using query interface is the solution. I still don't understand why normal c++ casting wouldn't work.

Comment: It would work, as I showed, as long as the interface pointer you stored is of the same type as the one you're casting to when using it.  If it's of a different type, it won't work (reliably) without `QueryInterface`, because you don't have any other runtime info.  E.g. with `IBase`, `IDerived1 : IBase` with 1 extra method and `IDerived2 : IBase` with 2 extra methods; what will happen if you cast an `IDerived1` to `IDerived2` (without checking) and either call the first extra method (assuming they have incompatible signatures) or call the second extra method?